# Excel index(match)

Tags: excel

In a spreadsheet, I am trying to show the highest number with a value smaller than 5040 in the column. Then, I would like to indicate the row where this number is.

I wrote 1000 lines. You can see below the lines I wrote in column B. They are the numbers starting with 10, 20, 30, and so forth until 1000.

[image: screenshot]

The function I wrote with `INDEX` doesn't check the whole column but only until it meets a bigger number. How can I fix it? Or should I use something else than `INDEX`?

Comment: Uh - I assume the link text is a joke...?  Could you also post some of the sample data here in a Table format (paste here, then use the code tags (`{}`) to format it). It'd help us work it out in Excel.

Comment: the function I wrote , Could you please show the function

Comment: =INDEX(A3:A102;MATCH(P4;C3:C102;1)*1)

Comment: What data would you like to see @BruceWayne? yeah, it was my cheesy joke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=INDEX(A:A;MATCH(AGGREGATE(14;6;B3:B102/(C3:C102<5040);1);B:B;0))
```

Comment: `It ain't working` is not a very descriptive error, and hard to help.

Comment: Ok, sorry. First of all I want to say that I appreciate your help very much, so thank you a lot. I am new to excel, so I have stupid question - am I supposed to copy this function into some cell? I did it but the broken formula error comes.

Comment: yes you are to copy and paste this in a cell.  I have edited it many times, try the new formula.

Comment: It gives me the same answer, which is 490. I copied your function and didn't change anything. Perhaps I could send youu excel file?

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you! I will have to say that I got help with this one tho, it's way too hard for a begginer like me to write something like that. How long does it take to get on that level, if I may ask? Thanks again! :D

Comment: Just need to be able to google what you want.  Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Can u tell me what should have I googled about this problem? That was one of my problems.

Comment: `MAX(IF())` or `Max if with Aggregate`  don't forget to mark as correct.

Comment: \*Makes yet another note to learn `AGGREGATE()`\*. Clever formula, I'll have to study it.

Comment: Marked. What I meant about googling is how did you come up with what do you have to google to solve this? I can't google "How to indicate certain value in certain row that fullfill those conditions"